# File name in awk after PIPE

Tags: python, file, unix, awk

FILENAME after each resulted line

```
awk '/Select User File/,/\*\*/' "{}"/* | grep "Rule" | sed 's/ //g' | sort -u
```

gives me the output as

```
Rule 123
Rule asd
Rule asdklnj
```

I want to append the `FILENAME` at the end of each line

I don't know how to get the file name after pipe

Comment: use `FILENAME` variable if you are using `gawk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get it after the pipe. Just put it in the `awk` command.

```
awk '/Select User File/,/\*\*/ {print $0 FILENAME}' "{}"/* | grep "Rule" | sed 's/ //g' | sort -u
```

There's also no need to use `grep` and `sed`, those can be done by `awk` itself.

```
awk '/Select User File/,/\*\*/ && /Rule/ {gsub(" ", ""); print $0, FILENAME}' "{}"/* | sort -u
```

Comment: The first method will remove potential spaces from the filename

Answer (score 1):

IMHO we could do this in a single `awk` itself or we could reduce commands in your attempt,since no samples are given then trying to fix OP's attempt itself, try following.

```
awk '/Select User File/,/\*\*/{gsub(/ /,"");print $0,FILENAME}' "{}"/* | grep "Rule" | sort -u
```